# Adding json data to json column is adding escape characters

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using postgres database, I have a table called names which has a column named 'info' which is of type json. I am adding

```
{ "info": "security" , description : "Sednit update: Analysis of Zebrocy: The Sednit group \u2013 also known as APT28, Fancy Bear, Sofacy or STRONTIUM \u2013 is a group of attackers operating since 2004, if not earlier, and whose main objective is to steal confidential information from specific targets.\n\nToward the end of 2015, we started seeing a new component deployed by the group; a downloader for the main Sednit backdoor, Xagent. Kaspersky mentioned this component for the first time in 2017 in their APT trend report and recently wrote an article where they quickly described it under the name Zebrocy.\n\nThis new component is a family of malware, comprising downloaders and backdoors written in Delphi and AutoIt. These components play the same role in the Sednit ecosystem as Seduploader; that of first-stage malware."}
```

Here I am using node js, with sequelize as orm. When I save it in table. I see "\\n" for "\n" and "\\u" for \u. Can anyone help me to avoid escaping characters while saving to table.

Answer (score 0):

> **I see \n for \n and \u for \u.**

In your **`json`** description is type of **`string`** , so it will convert the **new line/enter** to **\n** that the default behavior , or else you will not get the new line / enter when you try to fetch the data again.

And **\u** is for **unicode** , you might be saving some **smily** or **special character** so that will be converted to such strings.

**So there is no bug , this is how it works.**

Comment: I see "\\\\n" for \n

Comment: That might be coz of saving same string again and again , lets say you saved "\n" on first , if save same thing again will converted to "\\n" coz of backslash